# Sequelize is returning null values when used with include

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js, node-modules

When querying a model with include, incase of no rows available, it is returning data with null values.

I know this problem has been posted many times before, but i have not found any conclusions till now.

```
Model.findOne({
    where: { id: 1 },
    include: [{model: Model1}]
})
```

Result i am getting is like

```
{
    "id": null,
    "name": null,
    "age": null,
    "model1": []
}
```

If i use `raw: true`, it is printing like

```
{
    "id": null,
    "name": null,
    "age": null,
    "model1.model1n": 0
}
```

Comment: We probably need to show more of your code but what is Model1? Should it not be something like: `Model1.findOne({ where: { id: 1 } });` ?

Comment: Model and Model1 has 1:N relationship. I want to get all the Model1s for a particular Model.

Comment: Please also post the raw query generated by sequelize.js

Comment: @VivekDoshi Please check answer, i have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

One cause of this is if you exclude `id` from attributes. If you're using scopes or attributes in your includes or through tables, make sure you're returning the `id` primary key.

Another cause of this is if you return `null` in a custom `get()` getter function on the column.